# JPA find with condition not Key

Tags: jpa

I am using an EntityManager to persist my code. I am using the find method to retrieve the data. Is there any other method to read the data. I know I can use Query but I would be more comfortable if there is a method.

Comment: And is there anyway to get rid of the Key, something like findAll(where name="kk") ?

Comment: Have you looked into CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: Yes finally I ended up defining the @NamedQueries. I am pulling the data in many different places and I didn't want to build the query. With the NamedQuery annotation I can define them once and then use them wherever I want.